# PHP - create a hierarchical list from an array of subnets

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, ip

I have a multidimensional array that consists of IP addresses and subnet masks:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ip"]=>
    string(12) "192.168.0.0"
    ["mask"]=>
    int(22)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ip"]=>
    string(12) "192.168.0.0"
    ["mask"]=>
    int(30)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ip"]=>
    string(12) "192.168.0.4"
    ["mask"]=>
    int(31)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ip"]=>
    string(12) "192.168.0.4"
    ["mask"]=>
    int(32)
  }
}
```

The array is already in right order. The next I need to do is convert this array to a hierarchical list, the desired output should be something like this:

```
192.168.0.0/22
- 192.168.0.0/30
- 192.168.0.4/31
-- 192.168.0.4/32
```

Every time a subnet falls under a bigger subnet, the indent (' - ') must be increased by 1 as shown in the output above. I'm not working with predefined parent ID's because the list of subnets could change any moment. This conversion has to be done on the fly.

I wish I would have tried anything, but I don't know where to start. The only thing I can think of is comparing 2 subnets on every iteration through the array. First compare subnet 1 and 2, then 2 and 3, then 3 and 4, and so on...

Comment: have you tried something? share it please.

Comment: @Mohammad Not really, as I stated in my question I have no clue on where to start. I proposed a solution I could try, but how suitable would that be?

Comment: One of the issues you have with your example is that you're treating an IP address and a range as being interchangeable. A range does not necessarily fall into another range. You can run functions testing if a given IP is in a range, but ranges are not necessarily hierarchical the way your example shows.

Comment: Eg: how are you deciding that `192.168.0.0/30` exists as a child of `192.168.0.0/22`? Are you testing each IP in the range to make sure it's within its bounds?

Comment: Those addresses have the base address in common, and as a /30 is greater than a /22 in terms of integer values, i consider it as a child. 192.168.0.0/31 would be a child of the /30.

Comment: What about `192.168.0.4/22`? Where does that fit?

Comment: No where, first of all because it is a /22. The supernet already has a /22. Just as 192.168.0.4/32 falls within its parent with a /31, 192.168.0.5/32 also falls within that /31. This is basic subnetting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small class to handle the CIDR logic (simplifying the nesting process).

```
<?php
class Cidr {

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $subnet;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $mask;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $upperBound;

    /**
     * @var self[]
     */
    private $children = [];

    /**
     * Cidr constructor
     *
     * @param string $subnet
     * @param int    $mask
     */
    public function __construct($subnet, $mask) {
        $this->subnet     = ip2long($subnet);
        $this->mask       = (int) $mask;
        $this->upperBound = $this->subnet + pow(2, 32 - $this->mask) - 1;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $rangeStr
     *
     * @return Cidr
     */
    public static function fromString($rangeStr) {
        list($subnet, $mask) = explode('/', $rangeStr);
        return new self($subnet, $mask);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString() {
        return "{$this->minIp()}/{$this->mask}";
    }

    /**
     * @param Cidr $cidr
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function addChild(self $cidr) {
        if ($cidr === $this) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->isRangeInRange($cidr)) {
            foreach ($this->children as $child) {
                if ($child->addChild($cidr)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            $this->children[] = $cidr;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return Cidr[]
     */
    public function getChildren() {
        return $this->children;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function minIp() {
        return long2ip($this->subnet);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function maxIp() {
        return long2ip($this->upperBound);
    }

    /**
     * Check if an IP falls within this range
     *
     * @param string $ip
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isIpInRange($ip) {
        $mask = -1 << (32 - $this->mask);
        return (ip2long($ip) & $mask) === ($this->subnet & $mask);
    }

    /**
     * @param Cidr $cidr
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isRangeInRange(self $cidr) {
        return $cidr->subnet >= $this->subnet && $cidr->upperBound <= $this->upperBound;
    }

    /**
     * @param self[] $cidrs
     */
    public static function nestCidrs(array &$cidrs) {
        foreach ($cidrs as $a) {
            foreach ($cidrs as $k => $b) {
                if ($a !== $b && $a->addChild($b)) {
                    unset($cidrs[$k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param self[] $cidrs
     * @param int    $depth
     */
    public static function displayCidrs(array $cidrs, $depth = 0) {
        foreach ($cidrs as $cidr) {
            echo str_repeat('-', $depth) . "{$cidr}\n";
            self::displayCidrs($cidr->getChildren(), $depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Using an array of subnets (as you showed in your example):

```
$subnets = [
    [
        'ip'   => '192.168.0.0',
        'mask' => 22,
    ],
    [
        'ip'   => '192.168.0.0',
        'mask' => 30,
    ],
    [
        'ip'   => '192.168.0.4',
        'mask' => 31,
    ],
    [
        'ip'   => '192.168.0.4',
        'mask' => 32,
    ],
];
```

Create an array of `Cidr` objects:

```
$cidrs = [];
foreach ($subnets as $subnet) {
    $cidr = new Cidr($subnet['ip'], $subnet['mask']);
    $cidrs[(string) $cidr] = $cidr;
}
```

Run the nesting function (which will recursively add each subnet range to itself, as needed:

```
Cidr::nestCidrs($cidrs);
```

Then display the results:

```
Cidr::displayCidrs($cidrs);
```

Results:

```
192.168.0.0/22
-192.168.0.0/30
-192.168.0.4/31
--192.168.0.4/32
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the job very nicely! I'm studying the code to see if I understand the logic you're using :-)

Comment: How would I have CIDR list be returned as an array?

Comment: You can just choose not to run `Cidr::displayCidrs($cidrs);`. After running `Cidr::nestCidrs($cidrs);`, the `$cidrs` array is a nested array of `Cidr` objects. If you want, you can add a `toArray()` function to the class, and have it return an array with the keys `ip` and `mask`.

Comment: Ah I see. I actually got something working by adding a public static variable and modifying the displayCidrs function: `public static function displayCidrs(array $cidrs, $depth = 0) {
        foreach ($cidrs as $cidr) {
            self::$test .= '<tr><td>' . str_repeat('-', $depth) . "{$cidr} </td></tr>";
            self::displayCidrs($cidr->getChildren(), $depth + 1);
        }`